# Finding the Inverse of a Logarithmic Function with a Quadratic Argument

Tags: logarithms

$f(x)=\log_2(x^2-3x-4)$

Find $f^{-1}(x)$

My approach:

$y=\log_2(x^2-3x-4)$

$x=\log_2(y^2-3y-4)$

$2^x=y^2-3y-4$

$2^x+4=y(y-3)$

This is where I am stuck in my attempt on the problem.

Comment: Apply the formula for quadratic equations and check which of the solutions satisfy $x=\log_2(y^2-3y-4)$

Comment: @Peter I don't quite understand why we should use the quadratic formula in order to find the inverse function, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: You want to solve $y^2-3y-(2^x+4)=0$ for $y$

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is not injective. Inverse does not exist.